# QWebView can't display external image content set via javascript $("#<node_name>").html(<html_content>)

Tags: javascript, c++, html, qt, web

I'm migrating project from MFC to Qt now, and it's using embedded web browser, which displays local (resource) html-page. Local page is displayed fine, no problems. But i have a problem to set html content to  child tag. QWebView can't display external images set via javascript $("#").html() - only text and local (resource) images are displayed. In MFC version with IE webview the same script works fine.

I've tried to use QWebElement::setInnerXml, but result is the same: only local content is displayed.

After that i've tried to use QWebFrame::setHtml, but after call app crashes somewhere in QWebPuginDatabase::searchPathes, despite that i'm calling QWebFrame::setHtml from main thread.

Did anyone meet the same problem? Has anyone solution to resolve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change a setting, try:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(
    QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
```

The [`QWebSettings`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html) documentation describes the [attribute](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum) as (emphasis mine):

> Specifies whether locally loaded documents are allowed to access remote urls. **This is disabled by default.** For more information about security origins and local vs. remote content see [QWebSecurityOrigin](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsecurityorigin.html).

Comment: this option doesn't help. The same behavior either javascript function, nor QWebElement::setInnerXml method.

Comment: Are you calling the `setAttribute` line before creating the QWebView?

Comment: I've moved attribute set before ui creation. No changes.